# Help! 2018 Macbook pro - Monterey 12.6 crashing frequently

Tags: macbook-pro, crash

My MacBook is driving me nuts: constantly crashing - I will attach the crash report - i cant understand it - any help would be hugely appreciated, Thanks.

```
panic(cpu 10 caller 0xffffff8013b7999f): userspace watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from WindowServer in 120 seconds
service returned not alive with context : unresponsive work processor(s): WindowServer main thread is_alive_func returned unhealthy : Display 69734406 not ready: DisplayID: 0x4281006
    Surface Use Counts: 1(1) 2(3) 5(1) 
    FB RegID: 4294969701, On Glass SurfaceIDs: 1 5 2, Transactions: [ Active: Su
service: logd, total successful checkins since load (1740 seconds ago): 175, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
service: WindowServer, total successful checkins since load (1710 seconds ago): 159, last successful checkin: 120 seconds ago
service: remoted, total successful checkins since load (1740 seconds ago): 173, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
service: opendirectoryd, total successful checkins since load (1740 seconds ago): 175, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago

Panicked task 0xffffff99de7b8d10: 3 threads: pid 109: watchdogd
Backtrace (CPU 10), panicked thread: 0xffffff9511d8d540, Frame : Return Address
0xfffffff587fc3690 : 0xffffff801067fdad 
0xfffffff587fc36e0 : 0xffffff80107e10d6 
0xfffffff587fc3720 : 0xffffff80107d0443 
0xfffffff587fc3770 : 0xffffff801061fa70 
0xfffffff587fc3790 : 0xffffff801068017d 
0xfffffff587fc38b0 : 0xffffff801067f936 
0xfffffff587fc3910 : 0xffffff8010f15153 
0xfffffff587fc3a00 : 0xffffff8013b7999f 
0xfffffff587fc3a10 : 0xffffff8013b795f2 
0xfffffff587fc3a30 : 0xffffff8013b78971 
0xfffffff587fc3b60 : 0xffffff8010e838ec 
0xfffffff587fc3cc0 : 0xffffff8010786dd6 
0xfffffff587fc3dd0 : 0xffffff801065a9bb 
0xfffffff587fc3e60 : 0xffffff80106711e9 
0xfffffff587fc3ef0 : 0xffffff80107b30aa 
0xfffffff587fc3fa0 : 0xffffff8010620256 
     Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
        com.apple.driver.watchdog(1.0)[72F13DD7-D531-351F-8628-18318F125B22]@0xffffff8013b77000->0xffffff8013b79fff

Process name corresponding to current thread (0xffffff9511d8d540): watchdogd
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
21G115

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 21.6.0: Mon Aug 22 20:17:10 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.140.49~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 06A10466-36D7-3A0B-9EE7-A9053A8991A3
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000010400000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8010600000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000010410000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff8010610000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8010500000
System model name: MacBookPro15,1 (Mac-937A206F2EE63C01)
System shutdown begun: NO
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 1745102636954
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
 Uptime  : 0x0000019650391034
 Sleep   : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
 Wake    : 0x0000000000000000 0x000000c2f812799b 0x0000000000000000
Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 0 swapfiles and OK swap space
Zone info:
 Zone map: 0xffffff8044168000 - 0xffffffa044168000
 . PGZ   : 0xffffff8044168000 - 0xffffff8048169000
 . VM    : 0xffffff8048169000 - 0xffffff851449c000
 . RO    : 0xffffff851449c000 - 0xffffff86adb02000
 . GEN0  : 0xffffff86adb02000 - 0xffffff8b79e35000
 . GEN1  : 0xffffff8b79e35000 - 0xffffff9046168000
 . GEN2  : 0xffffff9046168000 - 0xffffff951249b000
 . GEN3  : 0xffffff951249b000 - 0xffffff99de7ce000
 . DATA  : 0xffffff99de7ce000 - 0xffffffa044168000
 Metadata: 0xffffffc0a4db8000 - 0xffffffc0c4db8000
 Bitmaps : 0xffffffc0c4db8000 - 0xffffffc0d0db8000

last started kext at 25470620586: >driverkit.serial 6.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7fa98b5000, size 28672)
last stopped kext at 1687919024171: @UVCService 1 (addr 0xffffff7fa98f9000, size 4096)
loaded kexts:
com.shinywhitebox.iShowU-Audio-Capture  1.0.4
com.uaudio.driver.UAD2System    9.15.0
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    2
```

Comment: You've got a lot of 3rd party audio kexts in there. I'd start by uninstalling those. Check iShowU & UA are up to date. I'd leave Soundflower out for now, even if it is the latest, or maybe try Blackhole [free] or something from Rogue Amoeba, Loopback etc [paid] instead.

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin, thanks for the suggestion mate - hey iv been trying to find and remove the software/kexts that you think maybe causing the issue, and i cant find them anywhere on my system, super frustrating! any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: https://support.shinywhitebox.com/hc/en-us/articles/204161529-Uninstalling-iShowU-Audio-Capture https://support.shinywhitebox.com/hc/en-us/articles/202751790-Uninstalling-Soundflower and [uaudio](https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/search?utf8=✓&query=uninstall&commit=Search)